# Passing python logging handles through to sub modules

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to get logging calls in sub modules to use handles defined in a parent script. Is this possible without passing the logger instance through directly?

For example, if I have a parent script like this:

parent.py

```
import sys
import logging
from child import child_function

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(10)

for _ in range(2):
    print('1. There was an old man named Michael Finnegan.')
    logger.info('2. He had whiskers on his chin-a-gen.')
    child_function()
```

child.py

```
import logging

def child_function():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info('3. The wind came up and blew them in again')
    print('4. Poor old Michael Finnegan, begin again.')
```

Then when I run parent.py I get:

```
1. There was an old man named Michael Finnegan.
2020-02-20 11:48:48,646 - __main__ - INFO - 2. He had whiskers on his chin-a-gen.
4. Poor old Michael Finnegan, begin again.
1. There was an old man named Michael Finnegan.
2020-02-20 11:48:48,646 - __main__ - INFO - 2. He had whiskers on his chin-a-gen.
4. Poor old Michael Finnegan, begin again.
```

So I'm missing line three! If I add logger as an argument to child_function()...

```
def child_function(parent_logger):
    logger = parent_logger.getChild(__name__)
    logger.info('3. The wind came up and blew them in again')
    print('4. Poor old Michael Finnegan, begin again.')
```

Then I get the expected result:

```
1. There was an old man named Michael Finnegan.
2020-02-20 11:54:10,988 - __main__ - INFO - 2. He had whiskers on his chin-a-gen.
2020-02-20 11:54:10,988 - __main__.child - INFO - 3. The wind came up and blew them in again
4. Poor old Michael Finnegan, begin again.
1. There was an old man named Michael Finnegan.
2020-02-20 11:54:10,988 - __main__ - INFO - 2. He had whiskers on his chin-a-gen.
2020-02-20 11:54:10,988 - __main__.child - INFO - 3. The wind came up and blew them in again
4. Poor old Michael Finnegan, begin again.
```

But I thought the idea of the getLogger(**main**) line was to get root loggers automatically. What have I misunderstood?

Comment: @metatoaster Brilliant, yes that works, thanks. Would you mind putting it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct because I spend ages trying to debug that this morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, if you want the actual root logger, call `getLogger()` without any arguments.

For some additional background details on what will be described below, please [refer to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) for how the `logging` module sets up the hierarchy.

What happened was that you called `getLogger(__name__)` in `parent.py`, that automatically gets a specific logger named with whatever that got assigned to `__name__`, rather than the root logger itself (since you executed the `parent.py` file directly, it becomes the `__main__` module).  As for `child.py`, it was imported as `child` so the `__name__` was set up as `child`, thus it really was one level down from the "root" logger and does not have any other parent.

Since the `logging` module use a dot (`.`) as the separator, this leads back to why you may have read some recommendation for the usage of `getLogger(__name__)` being a way to get a common parent to child loggers.  It may be noted that in Python, the namespace separator is also `.` such that `__name__` that is automatically available to any given module will be the canonical import name.

To illustrate with an example, given the following example package structure:

```
.
├── example
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── lib.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── submodule
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── demo1.py
│       └── demo2.py
└── setup.py
```

Inside `example/__init__.py`, a logger may be set up as such (to borrow part of your example):

```
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

This would in fact set up the "parent" logger for all loggers prefixed with `'example.'`, as `__name__` would resolve to `example` when another module does an `import example`.

Incidentally, this would also mean that the other modules such as `example.main` and even `example.submodule.demo1` (which those respective modules will also acquire their loggers with the same code, `getLogger(__name__)`), will now actually benefit from the handler and level that was set up by their relative root logger done inside the `example` module.  Likewise inside `example/submodule/__init__.py`, this module can acquire a common parent to everything logger prefixed with `'example.submodule.'` simply by assigning the result of `getLogger(__name__)` to a variable and make use of that.

Comment: This is a great answer. I had a comparable problem and luckily found this.